# Kubernetes: How to run MySQL command?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, devops

In Docker I can use the `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` in `docker-compose` file. How do I pass this while creating a MySQL Deployment?

I am using MySQL8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:8
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        args: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
```

Comment: Love you man. Being a newbie I found everyone referring `ConfigMap` for this and I was looking EXACTLY something similar. Can something similar be done at service end?

Comment: ConfiMap or even Secret or useful to set sensitive environment variables or files inside the container. The service is meant to be a kind of load balancer for multiple pods running.